# Fetch Data from same server on refreshing NEXT JS page

Tags: express, next.js

I am new to NextJS and i am stuck in a problem from few days. The problem is whenever i try to fetch data from same server (by same server, i mean the server on which i am running my next app), on refreshing the nextJS page, the page does not find the server route and throws an error 404 not found. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You mean you can open the page, but when you refresh that page it will become 404?